# How to properly call method asynchronous without blocking main thread?

Tags: python, asynchronous, concurrency, thread-safety

I have a service with some kind of **main-loop**. In this service I need to send request to other service with some metadata about operation. I need to do it asynchronous without blocking main thread.

Here is my code:

```
def process_response(self, request, response, spider):
    if self.enabled:
        Thread(target=self._send_request_to_information_supplier,
               args=(response,)).start()
        # I don't want this flow to be blocked by above thread.
        return response
    return response


def _send_request_to_information_supplier(self, html_response):
    some_metadata = InformationSupplierMetadata(url=html_response.url,
                                                html=html_response.text).convert_to_dict()
    try:
        request_response = requests.post(url=self.url,
                                         data=some_metadata,
                                         headers={'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8'},
                                         timeout=self.timeout,
                                         verify=False)
        self.logger.debug('Request was sent and end up with status {0}'.format(request_response.status_code))
    except ConnectTimeout:
        self.logger.debug('Request timed out')
```

I am beginner in multi-threading and I am not sure this is the correct way to do it. Maybe someone could suggest better approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use the `ThreadPoolExecutor`. Here is an example that may can help.

```
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor

executor = ThreadPoolExecutor(24)

def process_response(self, request, response, spider):
    if self.enabled:
        executor.submit(self._send_request_to_information_supplier, response)

        # I don't want this flow to be blocked by above thread.
        return response
    return response


def _send_request_to_information_supplier(self, html_response):
    ...
```

this way the executor will having 24 maximum number of threads, and the submit will run the method in one thread if any available.

Comment: If none thread gonna be available then what? Then operation gonna be stored in queue (RAM)? Could you explain why this approach is better than mine?

Comment: You may read some articles here: https://superfastpython.com/threadpoolexecutor-vs-threads/ for some explanations. From my point of view, I just think that you better create a instance to control the thread because you said it used for request and response,  some traffic concern and other concern that make me suggest ThreadPoolExecutor